# Arrange in increasing order of asymptotic complexity

Tags: asymptotics

[image: given time complexity]

I have to arrange the above time complexity function in increasing order of asymptotic complexity and indicate if there exist functions that belong to the same order.

So, my answer is

$[lg(n)]^2$  
$lg(2^n)$ and $log(2^n)$ and $2^{lg(n)}$ these belong to the same order of O(n)  
$nlog(n) + 1000 $
$n^{1.1}$

Just wish to check whether i'm right, since I'm not getting the same result as others.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you get $\log 2^n$ to be $O(\log n)$?

Comment: ... ah I see, @miracle173 edited the question to introduce an error. Rolled back now.

Comment: All look right to me now. Which different results are those "others" getting? (Except that it should be "same order of $\Theta(n)$").

Comment: [log(n)]^2
, lg(2n)=log(2n), nlog(n)+1000, n^1.1, 2lg(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am familiar with the question. (I am one of the **"others"**) I believe you neglected to specify that lg is log base 2.

In increasing order of asymptotic complexity:

---

$lg^2(n) = O(lg^2(n))$

---

$lg(2^n) = n = O(n)$

$log(2^n) = n * log(2) = O(n)$

$2^{lg(n)} = n = O(n)$

---

$n*log(n)+1000 = O(n log(n))$

---

$n^{1.1} = O(n^{1.1})$

Comment: Um, does that differ from the OP's result?

Comment: A solution was posted by our student organisation that was different and that's where the confusion was coming from... but that's settled now, unless of course this is actually wrong and someone here corrects this answer.